# Improve WooCommerce checkout process

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Woocommerce is setup to only ask for first name and email address.
They need to create an account.

When someone already has an account and tries to order for a second time, they need to log in first.

Instead they often fill in their name and email address and click checkout.

This results in an error: "Sorry the email address is already registered"

Most people just don't read and don't understand that they should log in first.

**Is it possible to REPLACE the Woo Error message with a popup login box? Preferrably a popup box that just asks their password?**

That wouldbe SO much more user friendly.

Kind regards,
M.

Comment: You can force users to be logged in to order in the WooCommerce settings.Would that suffice? It is possible to customize however if forcing users to login is not the route you want to take.